# mongodb geospatial subquery in array, how to return the array element nearest to the query?

Tags: mongodb

when I make a query to find the subdocument nearest to the query I make this :

The query :

```
       db.areas.findOne( 
               { 'coordinates.geoindex' :
               { $near : [ 2.364022, 48.896606 ] } 
               } 
               )
```

It return the document containing the array having the nearest element to the query.
But I'd like to find the nearest subelement.

For example for that query I should find the second array item "Aubervilliers" first.

Do you think that's possible ?

the document style :

```
                {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5199335f6db079ede30000"),
            "commercial_name" : "Paris area",
            "coordinates" : [ 
                {
                    "long_name" : "Arcueil",
                    "short_name" : "Arcueil",
                    "geoindex" : [ 
                        2.334955, 
                        48.80486
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name" : "Aubervilliers",
                    "short_name" : "Aubervilliers",
                    "geoindex" : [ 
                        2.384049, 
                        48.912259
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name" : "Bagnolet",
                    "short_name" : "Bagnolet",
                    "geoindex" : [ 
                        2.4234589, 
                        48.870364
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name" : "Boulogne-Billancourt",
                    "short_name" : "Boulogne-Billancourt",
                    "geoindex" : [ 
                        2.237803, 
                        48.84325
                    ]
                }, 
                {
                    "long_name" : "Charenton",
                    "short_name" : "Charenton-le-Pont",
                    "geoindex" : [ 
                        2.4158559, 
                        48.819918
                    ]
                }
        ...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry this isn't possible, the query chooses which documents to return and cannot shape how they are returned except for inclusion and exclusion of fields via projection. To do this you would need to store the data as separate documents.

Comment: Thank's ! I'll create separate collections with references.